# Sum with particular condition

Tags: r, sum

I would like to know some information, it is possible make a group by with this particular condition:

- Column Sepal.length take the first value;
- Sum the column that began with Petal
- Not select Sepal.Width

I have try this but I doesn't work:

```
m <- iris
    
m %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(across(starts_with("Petal"), sum)) %>% 
  summarise(F = first(Sepal.length))  # first for each Species
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: The sepal.leght (first value you see in the columns).
Column with petal name sum.
My code work but not at the same time, run the first and you see the sum, the second the first value

Comment: more row, group by is for Species

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

```
M = data.table(iris)
M[, 
  .(Petal.sum = sum(.SD), F = first(Sepal.Length)), 
  by = Species,
  .SDcols = patterns('^Petal')]

#       Species Petal.sum     F
#        <fctr>     <num> <num>
# 1:     setosa      85.4   5.1
# 2: versicolor     279.3   7.0
# 3:  virginica     378.9   6.3
```